# How to access other android application localstorage value in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have a application free and pro version, in this application user can store the values in localstorage values. But main problem is, if the user buy the paid version, they need some localstroage values from free version.

I think, we can access that application localstorage values using 64bit API key. But I can not search like that.

I can done it through user login and upload the localstorage value to my database and etc. But my application don't have the login process.

Comment: Couldn't you use an sqlite db and store it somewhere in the file system? Lots of apps create folders all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the free and paid versions are separate android applications then `localStorage` cannot be shared as it is application-contained